# Act as Bluetooth HID on Windows 10 to remote control an Android device

Tags: windows-10, android, bluetooth, remote-control

Is there a possibility to act as Bluetooth HID on Windows 10 to remote control an Android device so that no software needs to be installed on the smartphone?